# C++ Vector - Emplace/Erase not working?(Polymorphism)

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm having some problems with polymorphism I have a superclass of CEntity, and a subclass of unit type, I am dynamic casting and removing and emplacing a new entity of the dynamic casts type at its place, I have the opposite problem of my previous question.

Problem is the values being set are not changing, it remains with default values, it appeared to work before but now it has stopped working, I'm not sure what has caused the issue.

specifically buildsetup, sets the x-y-z values of the unit subclass's x,y,z, but when I look inside the vector the values remain unchanged, this is strange because it does actually manage to change the values for whether the unit is alive or not.

```
void builder(int no, string in , int top, int bot, CTeam &team, string owner, string original)
{

    for (int i = top; i <= bot; i++)
    {



        EntityUnit* a;
        a = dynamic_cast<EntityUnit*>(AWorld.EntitiesVector[i]);
        a->unit_alive;

        if (a->unit_alive == false)
        {
            float x = Player.returncity_add().cit_ret_X();
            float y = Player.returncity_add().cit_ret_Y();
            float z = Player.returncity_add().cit_ret_Z();
            cout << "X:" << x;
            cout << "Y:" << y;
            cout << "Z:" << z;
            float cost = MainAB.UnitTemplates[no]->UDRetCost();
            float health = MainAB.UnitTemplates[no]->UDRetMaxHealth();
            float damage = MainAB.UnitTemplates[no]->UDRetStrength();
            float speed = MainAB.UnitTemplates[no]->UDRetSpeed();
            float buildtime = MainAB.UnitTemplates[no]->UDRetBuildTime();
            int popcost = MainAB.UnitTemplates[no]->UDRetPop();


            a->set_owner(owner);

            setmodel(i, x, y, z); // takes an xyz by ref and sets the model 
           to them then changes the model's localz by -10 

            Units[i]->SetSkin(setskin(owner, original));

            a->BuildSetup(x, y, z, health, damage, speed, buildtime, cost, popcost);
            team.inc_popcount(a->UDRetPop());
            a->set_unit_alive(true);


            sBuildUnit.play();
            AWorld.EntitiesVector.erase(AWorld.EntitiesVector.begin() + i);
            AWorld.EntitiesVector.emplace(AWorld.EntitiesVector.begin() + i, new EntityUnit(a));
            AWorld.EntitiesVector[i]->set_x(x);
            AWorld.EntitiesVector[i]->set_y(y);
            AWorld.EntitiesVector[i]->set_z(z);

            break;
        }
}
```

Entity build setup

```
    void EntityUnit::BuildSetup(float x, float y, float z,float _health, float _damage, float _speed, float _buildtime, float _cost, int _popcost)
{
    unit_x = x;
    unit_y = y;
    unit_z = z;
    unit_health[0] = _health;
    unit_health[1] = _health;
    unit_damage = _damage;
    speed = _speed;
    buildtime = _buildtime;
    cost = _cost;
    CUnitType = NA;
    pop_req = _popcost;
}
```

After static debugging it, it most definately emplaces a new unit with the updated -is_alive, and while a's values change at the point of unitbuild, when its emplaced all x,y,z's return to 9999, which was what it was when they were pushed on the vector.

Comment: You seem to have a "copy" constructor that takes a pointer argument? That's smelly. And since `a` points at the same thing as the pointer inside the vector, any changes you made to `a` are already in the vector, and it doesn't seem to be necessary to erase and insert.  If you do, you probably ought to `delete a;` afterward, since it's no longer in the vector.  All that said, there's not enough information here to identify your problem.  Please try to prepare a [mcve], remembering to take out irrelevant things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
AWorld.EntitiesVector.erase(AWorld.EntitiesVector.begin() + i);
```

you destroy the object pointed to by `a`.  The subsequent reference to it on the next line is Undefined Behavior, and anything is possible.

I'm not sure why you erase the entity, then try to put a new one in the same place.  If you structure your code right you should be able to just reuse the existing entity (pointed to by a) without the erase and emplace calls.

Comment: what do you mean ? structure correctly ? :( I'm not very experienced in the subject matter, if i just dynamic cast will that change the vector entity anyway ?

Comment: `a` is not an iterator, reference, or pointer to an element of the vector; it is a converted copy of the (pointer) element of the vector.  Why would it be invalidated or `*a` destroyed?

Comment: @RNewell122 Basically you need to ensure that all the members of the reused entity get properly initialized.  Since you're reusing the memory, and not creating a new one, no constructor is called to do this for you.  In your case it seems likely that this is already done since that's essentially what you're already doing with the `new EntityUnit` call.

Comment: @aschepler `a` is a pointer into `AWorld.EntitiesVector`, so when that element is erased what `a` points to changes.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm sorry, I'm really struggling to understand, when I call newentityunit, it should initialize all the EntityUnit with my constructor?

Comment: @RNewell122 I don't know.  That depends on what the `EntityUnit(EntityUnit *)` constructor does.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It is *not* a pointer to an element of the vector.  That would look like `auto* ptr = &AWorld.EntitiesVector[i];` (and there would be no point in `dynamic_cast`, since the type of a vector element is fixed).

Comment: @aschepler `AWorld.EntitiesVector[i]` is apparently a pointer to something.  We don't know what kind, so we don't know if its destructor is called when the element is erased.  So `a` may or may not still be valid.  I'm assuming that the vector is doing so; you're not.

Comment: a is a pointer to EntityUnit which is subclass of Entity 
Vector<Entity*>EntitiesVector - consists of entities and units

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm A vector of pointers never deletes those pointers or otherwise does anything at all to the pointed-at objects.

Comment: @RNewell122 is `Vector` `std::vector`?  That info should be in the question.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm sorry yes std::vector

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Apparently the problem was it was totally unnecessary to erase/emplace, as I get what you mean now returning a pointer, it edited the value... odd it didn't work last time.